# Font face (highlighting) of single-quoted strings stopped working after update

Tags: font-lock

I'm using a [custom mode](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/haxe-mode/blob/master/haxe-mode.el) that I believe is based on `cc-mode`, and it's been working great for years. Recently, I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, which brought Emacs to 26.3 (I forget what it was before, maybe 25.2.2), and now, my single-quoted strings are not being highlighted correctly anymore (while double-quoted strings are working fine):

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: My suggestion, unless you happen to get a helpful answer here, is to contact the maintainer of that code.

Comment: That's a fine suggestion, @Drew, thanks. I was just hoping some emacs-minded folks here could help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't want to downgrade emacs for a simple formatting problem, but I suppose that's my option as I wait for a better answer.

I didn't find a repo for 20.04 with old emacs 25, so I built it from source. Here's what I did, in case you or I have to do it again:

First, remove apt-installed emacs:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge emacs emacs-gtk
```

Download http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/gnu/emacs/emacs-25.2.tar.gz - personally I untarred it in `/opt/` which may require sudo or chown

My first `./configure` complained about missing support for gif, tiff, and xpm -- don't care, build without.

```
cd /opt/emacs-25.2
./configure --with-xpm=no --with-gif=no --with-tiff=no
make
```

Finally, symlink this to `/usr/bin/emacs` so it's available system-wide:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/emacs-25.2/src/emacs /usr/bin/emacs
```

And voila, the formatting works again, highlighting single-or-double quoted strings the same:

[image]